# SQL-Should I use nested Query to first correct erroneous data and then convert to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion, subquery

There is one column: OpenedDate with datatype: varchar(8) and I want to convert it into datetime but since OpenedDate has erroneous values of 0's.
First- I want to convert the 0's into NULLs using the query:
CASE WHEN Opened_dt = '0' 
    then 'NULL'
    else Opened_dt
    end as 'Opened_dt_converted'
Now, I want to use the above results to convert the datatype to DateTime using the syntax:
CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Opened_dt_converted',120)

I was thinking if I should use Nested query or create a stored procedure but I am not sure how can I use the nested query for this type of situation?
Basically, I want this whole query in one stored procedure. Could you please help me in achieving that task?

Thanks in advance!
Geetanjali

Comment: If this is SQL Server 2012 or later, you could use [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx), which will return  NULL for values it can't parse.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, just use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(DateTime, OpenedDate, 120)
```

If it fails, then you'll get `NULL`.  In older versions, you would just use a `case`:

```
select (case when OpenedDate like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'
             then convert(DateTime, OpenedDate, 120)
        end)
```

Note:  I just put in a format that would often work for `date`.  The `time` component is similar.

Answer (score 1):

`Sub-select` or `CTE` should work for you.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Opened_dt_converted, 120) AS dt_converted
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN Opened_dt = '0' THEN NULL
                 ELSE Opened_dt
               END AS Opened_dt_converted
        FROM   yourtable) a
```

or use `Case` statement to skip the zero from convertion

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Opened_dt = '0' THEN NULL
         ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, Opened_dt, 120)
       END AS dt_converted
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: I don't think that `NULL` should be in quotes.

Comment: @Turophile - Yeah didn't see it. Updated

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Opened_dt_converted, 120) AS dt_converted
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN Opened_dt = '0' THEN NULL
                 ELSE Opened_dt
               END AS Opened_dt_converted
        FROM   yourtable) a                                                                                                    When i use the above query, it throws the error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. What is causing the error here?